# Как перевести тип string в тип number, если тип содержит число

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Пример типа:

```typescript
type MyStringNumber = '10'
```

Необходимо так:

```typescript
type MyNumber = StringToNumber<MyStringNumber> // -> number
```

Как можно реализовать такой тип?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так, используя ограничения и `infer`:

```typescript
type StringToNumber<S extends `${number | bigint}`> = 
  S extends `${infer N extends number | bigint}`
    ? N
    : never;
```